# changing my ip based url to name based url

Tags: php, ubuntu, drupal

basically i have my website under `91.xx.xx.76/mywebsite` in folder `/var/www/mywebsite`

and i want the user to type `www.mywebsite.com`, i have search some methods in doing so but doesn't actually solve it. they say to create a file under `sites-available` then enabled it

i have created file under `sites-available` and also enabled it using `a2ensite mywebsite`, then restarted apache2 using `service apache2 restart` then i try to load `www.website.com` but it loads nothing..

any help?
thanks

Comment: Have you registered the domain `website.com` and set up DNS accordingly to point to your server...?!

Comment: can you post file under sites-avaiable to here?

Answer (score 0):

To use "name based URLs", you need to register the *domain* you wish to use in the global *Domain Name System* (DNS). Just setting some configuration in your own server is not enough; anybody could do that, which means there could be any number of people claiming the domain `www.website.com` at the same time. That's not how it works.

Find yourself a *domain name registrar* whom you'll wire a small amount of money in exchange for registering your desired domain. This purchases you the rights to set the DNS configuration of said domain to point its `A` record to your server's IP address.* This is what enables you to resolve `www.website.com` to your server. Then you only need to configure your server appropriately to serve requests for `www.website.com`.

<sub>* More correctly, it purchases you the right to set the `NS` record of the domain to point to a *name server* you control on which you can set any number of DNS records you want, including the `A` record. Most registrars also offer a name server as part of the deal of purchasing a domain, but those are actually separate things.</sub>

Comment: oh i see! i now have my www.website.com enabled and payed. my website is now rerouted to www.website.com but the problem now is whenever i click a link under my website the url should become www.website.com/link but instead it stays them same, the page change tho.

Comment: Well, if you are linking to a URL with the IP address in it, then that's what you'll get. Don't link to your IP address.

Comment: im using drupal by the way, so the menu is automatically created and is linked to `$base_url/menu1` where `$base_url` is route to my IP `91.xx.xx.xx/mywebsite`

Comment: Then you need to change your baseurl, no idea how to do that in Drupal.

Comment: i know how, but, if i change the whole drupal will be destroyed, and by the way. i tried to create link that is linked to www.website.com/sample.. it still does not change the url, but the sample page is showing.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand your current predicament. The fact is you need to link to your pages the way you want your links to look; if you want `www.website.com/foo` then you need to link to `www.website.com/foo`, not to the IP address. I have no experience with Drupal here to help you with that.

Comment: sorry for not explaining well.. yes i did do that.... `<a href="www.website.com/foo">link</a>`, the pages loaded, but my url in the address bar is still `www.mywebsite.com`

Comment: And what would you expect/like it to be instead?

Comment: i hoped it should be `www.mywebsite.com/foo`

Comment: Yes, it should be indeed. Are you saying you are *seeing* the site `www.website.com/foo` but the address in the browser's address bar still looks like `www.website.com`? That's only possible if your site is displayed in an HTML frame (or Javascript or other client-side trickery, but not any server configuration or DNS setup for sure).

Comment: yes you're right, i am seeing `www.website.com/foo` but the url is still `www.mywebsite.com`, oh is that so, but when i use the ip base url it is changing, like when i used `91.xx.xx.xx/mywebsite` then click the link `<a href="91.xx.xx.xx/mywebsite/foo">link</a>` the url goes to `91.xx.xx.xx/mywebsite/foo` and i see `91.xx.xx.xx/mywebsite/foo` which is correct.